# dplyr row_number with multiple order columns

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr

I am looking to filter on a row number whose order is determined by two columns instead of just one:

```
pg <- src_postgres()
dat <- tbl(pg, 'table')

rows <- dat %>%
  group_by(dimension) %>%
  filter(row_number(date1, date2) == 1)
```

This produces the error:

`Error in row_number(date1, date2) : unused argument (date2)`

I could accomplish the above without error by reworking the problem as seen below but that seems like overkill, especially if I need to order by 3+ columns. Is there some functionality to row_number that I am missing that would make this less verbose?

```
rows <- dat %>%
  group_by(dimension, date1) %>%
  filter(row_number(date2) == 1) %>%
  group_by(dimension) %>%
  filter(row_number(date1) == 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
dat %>%
  arrange(dimension, date1, date2) %>%
  group_by(dimension) %>%
  filter(1:n() == 1)
```

Comment: Because I am doing the work in-database the slice functionality is out of the question.

I will have to use the row_number function with both date1 and date2 in the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: This still does not work.

Keep in mind that I am not collecting this data. I intend to use dplyr to manipulate the data in-db. Your solution works somewhat when I collect() but I need a way to have dplyr construct the OVER clause correctly for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

Not very elegant, but it works:

```
rows <- dat %>%
  group_by(dimension) %>%
  filter(row_number(paste0(date1, date2)) == 1L)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one, this should help.

```
row_num <- function(...){
  l <- list(...)
  names(l) <- paste0("col",1:length(l))
  data.frame(l) %>% 
    mutate(org_pos = row_number()) %>%
    arrange(across(names(l))) %>% 
    mutate(pos = row_number()) %>% 
    arrange(org_pos) %>%
    pull(pos)
}

rows <- dat %>%
  group_by(dimension) %>%
  filter(row_num(date1, date2) == 1)
```